# How to load data in store object in extjs

Tags: extjs4

```
Ext.define('ParolePoint', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['state', 'entry', 'exit']
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'ParolePoint',
        data : [

  {state: 'Connecticut', entry: 45000, exit:28211},
  {state: 'Maine', entry:3627, exit:3692},
  {state: 'Massachusetts', entry:98952, exit:96142},
  {state: 'New Hampshire', entry:3789, exit:3697},
  {state: 'New Jersey', entry:49728, exit:55858},
  {state: 'New York', entry:62419, exit:64147},
  {state: 'Pennsylvania', entry:13966, exit:13240},
  {state: 'Rhode Island', entry:6262, exit:6012},
  {state: 'Vermont', entry:4884, exit:5487},
]
});
 store.loadData(data);

 document.write(store.state);
```

I am currently using raw data that i have been providing but i want to take input from user directly which i am not getting. Please helo i am new to extjs 4 ??

Comment: Create a panel and feed the input into the model fields then you can achieve what you are expecting.I am also new to extJS

Comment: Thanks @NeverGiveUp161 for your response... However I switched to angular 2 now :)

Comment: nice :) for angular is yet to come :D waiting for the opportunity